# grid view set focus on cursor on enter event in win-form application

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on windows application.I have a grid view like this:

[image]

In this if i give id in my first `column(Eid)` then i will enter that time i have to get cursor focus on 3 rd `coulmn(Eno)` the same row.if i enter again in 3rd colum cursor need to move on 4th column `(Eaddress)` of the same row.

how i can achieve this? any help is very appreciable..thanks in advance

Comment: You could just reorder the columns like eid, eno, eaddress, ename and then press Tab to move to focus on the next column

Comment: no sir..while clicking enter button i want to move my cursor position to 3 rd column

Comment: Your question has many problems. Please, when dealing with computers and when asking questions on SO always try to be precise! - __Enter__ is a key on the __keyboard__, not a __button__. You don't __click__ it, you __press__ it and this results in several __keyboard events__, none of which is the 'Enter' __event__! (Which happens when your __mouse enters__ the Control..!) . Note: This is not about the English laguage, this is about several __misleading__ words in your question!

Answer (score 1):

I think creating your own, custom `dataGridView` with overriden `ProcessDialogKey` method, will be a good idea.

I nested `CustomDataGrid` class inside `Form` class just for clarity of the example, it should be moved to separate class file.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public class CustomDataGridView : DataGridView
        {
            protected override bool ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
            {
                //if enter pressed
                if (keyData == Keys.Enter)
                {
                    //return if no selected cells
                    if (this.CurrentCell == null)
                        return true;

                    //if current column is first column
                    if (this.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0)
                        //move on to third
                        changeCurrentColumn(2, this.CurrentCell.RowIndex);

                    //if current column is thrid column
                    else if (this.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 2)
                        //move on to fourth
                        changeCurrentColumn(3, this.CurrentCell.RowIndex);

                    //if we're in last column
                    else if (this.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == this.Columns.Count - 1)
                        //go one row down and to the first column
                        changeCurrentColumn(0, this.CurrentCell.RowIndex + 1);

                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return base.ProcessDialogKey(keyData);
                }
            }
            private void changeCurrentColumn(int columnToMoveTo, int currentRow)
            {
                //move on to next column
                this.CurrentCell = this.Rows[currentRow].Cells[columnToMoveTo];
                //and start editing
                this.BeginEdit(true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Just in case you (or somebody else) don't know how to use it:
Go to `ToolBox`, right click, select `ChooseItems...`, click `Browse` button and select exe or dll file with your `customDataGrid`. Hit `Ok` to close window.

[image: Add newly created control to ToolBox]

Your `customDataGrid` should be now inside `ToolBox`. Put it on your form.

[image: customDataGrid inside Toolbox]

Here's how it works when you hit enter

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]